# Corrupt JPEG data: 214 extraneous bytes before marker 0xd9 BUT DONT HAVE JPEG IMAGES

Tags: python, image, error-handling, jpeg, jupyter-lab

I am working with the code bellow, and I am sure that my data_dir doesnt have any jpeg image, all in the jpg format. but not sure having the error of corrupt JPEG data.

```
#image standard
image_exts = ['jpeg','jpg', 'bmp', 'png']
#remove the image which outside the standard
for image_class in os.listdir(data_dir): #looping through every single of directory (cat/dog)
    for image in os.listdir(os.path.join(data_dir, image_class)): #loop through every single image inside the subdir
        #join -> data->cat, data->dog
        image_path = os.path.join(data_dir, image_class, image) #grabbing every single image
        try: 
            img = cv2.imread(image_path) #allow open up an image
            tip = imghdr.what(image_path) #check the type of img
            if tip not in image_exts: 
                print('Image not in ext list {}'.format(image_path))
                os.remove(image_path) #if not a valid image, extension-> delete the file
        except Exception as e: 
            print('Issue with image {}'.format(image_path))
            # os.remove(image_path)
```

[image: error pop out]

Comment: There was enough of the file probably to decode it but a spurious EOI 0xff,0xd9 somewhere with some extra spurious bytes ahead of it. JPEG and JPG are the same file format for the purposes of the JPEG decoding library just different file extensions commonly used.